# How to make navigation bar in to a carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making website which is responsive.There is one horizontal navigation bar which on decreasing screen size will convert into a drop-down menu.On clicking of each tag different image will load into a div. 
Now please help me in changing navigation bar into a carousel instead of drop-down..

Comment: is there any other way ..i want to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple answer- use media query, hide navigation bar when you go to certain display size and show carousel using `display:block` and `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

You may customize your navigation and make it a carousel. I recommend using [this carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/). You have to customize it and give an item limit for desktop viewports and also give a different item limit for mobile and tab viewports. I think there are still many ways to solve your problem but I think this works for me. Hope it helps